# Is there a single word to lay emphasis on something?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there such a word that does this?

> He's a scientist, a natural scientist _______.
>   That is a crime, a federal one _______.

A single word which emphasizes a preceding statement by/and giving additional information, used more often after the phrase being emphasized, and not exactly "not to mention".

Comment: Do you insist on the emphasiser being in the indicated position?  The suggestions 'specifically', 'indeed', 'moreover', 'futher', and 'even' below all convey the indicated sense, but (I believe) read extremely strangely when put where suggested.  The suggestion "as a matter of fact" (http://english.stackexchange.com/a/311979/64759) would suffer from the same issue, except that @Graffito explicitly moves it.

Answer (score 19):

> He's a scientist, a natural scientist **to boot**.
>   That is a crime, a federal one **at that**.

And if you absolutely insist on it being a single word, you can use *even* or *actually*.

Comment: This is the only suggestion of the bunch so far that makes sense (at least, to me) when placed in the indicated position.

Comment: This would sound better to me with an "and" after the comma.

Answer (score 12):

I'll add in my 2 cents for **no less**, as in:

> He's a scientist; a natural scientist no less.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for, although not a single word, it puts more emphasis on the preceding statement somewhat like "not only... but also...". I remember an example from "The Big Bang Theory" where Sheldon said "Yeah, and then she went behind my back to help someone else prove me wrong. My rival, no less."

Answer (score 10):

You can try ***specifically***:

From [Collins Thesaurus of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/specifically):

> *adverb*
> 2. precisely, exactly, explicitly, unambiguously  -  *brain cells, or more specifically, neurons*

Therefore:

> He is a scientist, a natural scientist *specifically*.
>
> That is a crime, a federal crime *specifically*.

You can also put it in front of the additional information:

> That is a crime- *specifically*, a federal crime.

---

<sup><sub>1. Collins Thesaurus of the English Language – Complete and Unabridged 2nd Edition. 2002 © HarperCollins Publishers 1995, 2002</sub></sup>

Comment: I wouldn't say that 'specifically' _emphasises_ (like say 'at that' does). It _specifies_.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using [**indeed**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/indeed) which is an adverb:

> Used to emphasize a statement or response confirming something already
>   suggested
>
> Used to emphasize a description: '*it was a very good buy indeed*'

Your example:

> He's a scientist, a natural scientist indeed.
>   That is a crime, a
>   federal one indeed.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Answer (score 1):

Consider "[as a matter of fact](http://%20used%20to%20%E2%80%8Badd%20something%20more%20to%20what%20you%20have%20just%20said:%20The%20%E2%80%8Bshoes%20are%20still%20%E2%80%8Bstylish,%20and%20as%20a%20matter%20of%20%E2%80%8Bfact%20,%20I'm%20%E2%80%8Bwearing%20a%20%E2%80%8Bpair%20%E2%80%8Bright%20now.%20%E2%80%BA%20used%20to%20say%20that%20you%20do%20not%20%E2%80%8Bagree%20with%20what%20someone%20has%20just%20said%20or%20that%20the%20%E2%80%8Bopposite%20of%20what%20they%20say%20is%20%E2%80%8Btrue:%20We're%20not%20%E2%80%8Blosing%20%E2%80%8Bpopulation%20in%20%E2%80%8Bour%20%E2%80%8Btown.%20As%20a%20matter%20of%20%E2%80%8Bfact,%20%E2%80%8Bpeople%20are%20%E2%80%8Bmoving%20in.)":

> He's a scientist, **as a matter of fact**, a natural scientist.
>
> That is a crime, **and as a matter of fact**, a federal one.

Answer (score 1):

> He's a scientist, a natural scientist **even**

Answer (score 0):

He's a scientist, a natural scientist *moreover*.

That is a crime, a federal one *further*.

Answer (score 0):

**evidently**
ˈɛvɪd(ə)ntli/Submit
adverb
1.
in a way that is clearly seen or understood; obviously.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/evidently

Answer (score 0):

It's two words, but **in fact** also works for these.

> He's a scientist, a natural scientist in fact.
>
> That is a crime, a federal one in fact.

Answer (score 0):

I think **namely** is the word you are looking for.

According to [Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/namely):

> —used when giving exact information about something you have already mentioned

Answer (score -1):

Extraordinaire

adjective ex·traor·di·naire \ik-ˌstrȯ(r)-də-ˈner, ek-\
Definition of extraordinaire:

> Extraordinary —used postpositively a chef extraordinaire

Examples of extraordinaire in a sentence

> The sort of chef extraordinaire who can whip up a fantastic meal, regardless of the ingredients on hand.

(from [Webster's](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extraordinaire))

Answer (score -1):

> fur shur

It's in the dictionary: [fur shur, adverb](https://books.google.com/books?id=5F-YNZRv-VMC&pg=PA360&lpg=PA360&dq=valley%20girl%20fur%20shur&source=bl&ots=mjw1WwaJVp&sig=ncgz2oQ1cfTtNAhuqUqsY3axHoE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBzrfQw63LAhVIWj4KHWKcCQIQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=valley%20girl%20fur%20shur&f=false).

Comment: Or, if you don't want to use slang, "for sure" is the correct spelling. And isn't  in a "Dictionary of Modern American Slang and Unconventional English".

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Not even really slang; just an incorrect spelling.  Also, this doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, I found "fur shur" with a Google search -- maybe you misspelled it.  "Shur" in valley girl speech is not pronounced like I would say "sure", since "shur" has a syllabic r rather than a tense u.

Answer (score -1):

**just**
often used for emphasizing a statement, it means: *[no more than; merely; only](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/just)*. Note that the first clause is in the negative.

- He isn't *just* a scientist, he's a natural scientist
- That's not *just* a crime, it's a federal crime.